# MySQL asks password every time

Tags: passwords, mysql-cli

Server: Ubuntu 20.04

MySQL version: MySQL Server version: 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1

No changes in config were made. But server was rebooted and `dpkg.log` is lost, so I can't say was there update since last time or not.

Problem is that earlier when I connect using `mysql -u user -p` and input password, than I can change databases through `\r DB` and do other things with no password prompt. Now when I trying to switch DB than `MySQL` asks me a password, that's just uncomfortable. `Man` shows nothing, or I'm blind. In google all links lead to reset root password pages... which are millions.

`show grants;` on user shows that privileges are same and sufficient, user are root in fact but with other name.

Comment: _user are root in fact but with other name._ What does that mean

Comment: Please demonstrate what you mean by using `/r DB`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Same rights that root have. Grant all on "\*.\*" with grant privileges. Demonstrate what? \r DB it's a standard command to switch DB inside mysql cli tool. When I enter it, than mysql shows me standart "Enter password:" request